# Connection between BlackBerry Simulator & MDS

Tags: blackberry

I recently started working on BlackBerry Simulators 9800. Few doubts are bugging me while I work on this

1. I would like to know how the simulator knows about the MDS server if we change the default port.
2. I saw there is an option to mention the MDS IP & Port in simulator batch file.but most of the forums doesn't talk about it.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

1)  There are a number of ports you can configure.  The port the BlackBerry smartphone simulator uses to connect to the MDS-CS Simulator is not one of them.

2)  What parameter are you referring to here?

Comment: The default port for MDS is 8080. If we change to 8090 ,how does the simulator know about MDS service?